# How can I get the file path to my picture (HTML & JS)

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to get my picture's SRC path file link

At the moment my code looks like this

```js
picture.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.src)
})
```

This prints something like this

```js
http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/code-mobile.png
```

And what I really want is just the bit that looks like

```js
/img/code-mobile.png
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `URL` class to parse the URL for you:

```js
picture.addEventListener("click", (e) => {   
  var url = new URL(e.target.src);
  console.log(url.pathname);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
picture.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(new URL(e.target.src).pathname)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the relative path instead of the absolute one, use getAttribute('src') instead of src in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the host string from `window.location.host` and then replace it with an empty string in the url.

something like:

```
picture.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let imageSrc = e.target.src.replace(window.location.href,'');
  console.log(imageSrc);
})
```